openpyxl in VS Studio not displaying tuples from linked Excel file
I have been following this video tutorial.
At time 36:48, after applying "Run Code" run option, the tuples read from the xlsx file are displayed under the "OUTPUT" tab.
My problem:

The tuples aren't being displayed as in the video. My code:

Python
 
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import openpyxl

def load_data():
    path = 'C:/Python exercises/people/people.xlsx'
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
    sheet = workbook.active
    
    list_values = list(sheet.values)
    print(list_values)
    
    for col_name in list_values[0]:
        treeview.heading(col_name, text=col_name)

    for value_tuple in list_values[1:]:
        treeview.insert('', tk.END, values=value_tuple)

def insert_row():
    name = name_entry.get()
    age = int(age_spinbox.get())
    subscription_status = status_combobox.get()
    employment_status = 'Employed' if a.get() else 'Unemployed'

    print(name, age, subscription_status, employment_status)

    path = 'C:/Python exercises/people/people.xlsx'
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
    sheet = workbook.active
    row_values = [name, age, subscription_status, employment_status]
    sheet.append(row_values)
    workbook.save(path)    

    treeview.insert('', tk.END, values=row_values)

    name_entry.delete(0, 'end')
    name_entry.insert(0, 'Name')
    age_spinbox.delete(0, 'end')
    age_spinbox.insert(0, 'Age')
    status_combobox.set(combo_list[0])
    checkbutton.state(['selected']) 

def toggle_mode():
    if mode_switch.instate(['selected']):
        style.theme_use('forest-light')
    else:
        style.theme_use('forest-dark')

root = tk.Tk()

style = ttk.Style(root)
root.tk.call('source', 'forest-light.tcl')
root.tk.call('source', 'forest-dark.tcl')
style.theme_use('forest-dark')
combo_list = ['Subscribed', 'Not Subscribed', 'Other'] 
frame = ttk.Frame(root) 
frame.pack()   

widgets_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(frame, text='Insert Row') 
widgets_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=10) 

name_entry = ttk.Entry(widgets_frame)
name_entry.insert(0, 'Name') 
name_entry.bind('<FocusIn>', lambda e: name_entry.delete('0', 'end')) 
name_entry.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady = (0, 5), sticky='ew') 

age_spinbox = ttk.Spinbox(widgets_frame, from_=18, to=100) 
age_spinbox.insert(0, 'Age')
age_spinbox.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='ew')

status_combobox = ttk.Combobox(widgets_frame, values=combo_list)
status_combobox.current(0)
status_combobox.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='ew')

a = tk.BooleanVar()
checkbutton = ttk.Checkbutton(widgets_frame, text='Employed', variable=a)
checkbutton.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='nsew')

button = ttk.Button(widgets_frame, text='Insert', command=insert_row)
button.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='nsew')

separator = ttk.Separator(widgets_frame)
separator.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=(20, 10), pady=10, sticky='ew')

mode_switch = ttk.Checkbutton(widgets_frame, text='Mode', style='Switch', 
command=toggle_mode)
mode_switch.grid(row=6, column=0, padx=5, pady=10, sticky='nsew')

treeFrame = ttk.Frame(frame)
treeFrame.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=10)
treeScroll = ttk.Scrollbar(treeFrame)
treeScroll.pack(side='right', fill='y')
cols = ('Name', 'Age', 'Subscription', 'Employment')
treeview = ttk.Treeview(treeFrame, show='headings', yscrollcommand=treeScroll.set, columns=cols, height=13)
treeview.column('Name', width=100)
treeview.column('Age', width=50)
treeview.column('Subscription', width=100)
treeview.column('Employment', width=100)
treeview.pack()
treeScroll.config(command=treeview.yview)

root.mainloop()


I have been able to get the GUI alright but the column titles are missing.

Note: I am able to make new entries onto the Excel file from the GUI as shown in the follow-up steps in video. No issue there.
It looks like the xlsx is readable so this may not be the problem just the contents not being called-up in the GUI.
Screenshot of terminal from the tutorial:

Screenshot of results: 

What I say is according to your screenshot, the first index of the list is the column names. Is that correct?

@Mohsen_Fatemi Yes, but I hope you've noted it's a screenshot from the tutorial. It's what I want to achieve.

Then add the screenshot of your code with result

@Mohsen_Fatemi Full code and results added

Images bad, text formatted as code is how you should be adding your code samples to the Post. Never post screenshots of code.

@moken -As mentioned previously, I am actually able to add entries onto the spreadsheet from the GUI. -Yes, I have used the .xlsx file provided. -That the right hand side of the GUI is not being populated is the issue i.e. both the headers and cell contents underneath -Previous commenter asked for a screenshot of the code

Yes, agreed the screenshot was asked for, don't know why. Posting screenshots of code can get your Question closed. You can appreciate it's more difficult to transpose your code and run it from a screen shot than just copy/paste the formatted code.

But I did transpose your code and like I said I didn't find any problems and it worked correctly for me. The only thing missing in the screenshot is you do not call the function load_data(). This function should be called just before root.mainloop() right at the end of the code, I.e should be the next line after treeScroll.config(command=treeview.yview) .Check and add if it's missing.

The tuples and full table are now displayed. Solved. Thanks
